# CAKEPHP - Undefined Index on production server

Tags: cakephp

I put my application in a production server on the web and, it's not recognize any of my models.

In my local server this works fine...

This give this error on foreach datas.
`Undefined index: Power`

I have this in my controller:

```
$this->set('poderes',$this->Attorney->Power->find('all'));
```

This in my view:

```
 ?php foreach ($poderes as $power):  ?>
    <?php debug($power) ?>
    <div class="checkbox tooltip" title="<?php echo $power['Power']['texto'] ?>">
    <input type="checkbox" name="data[Power][Power][]" value="<?php echo $power['Power']['id'] ?>"  id="PowerPower<?php echo $power['Power']['id'] ?>" />
    <label><?php echo $power['Power']['resumo'] ?></label>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

In my Local server this is the debug of `$power`:

```
array(
'Power' => array(
    'id' => '1',
    'resumo' => 'Negociacao',
    'texto' => '<b>(a)</b> formalizar a transmissao, novacaoo, confissao, dacao em pagamento e transacao de obrigacoes cujo sujeito ativo (credora) seja a OUTORGANTE e as obrigacoes sejam decorrentes de suas operacoes;',
    'teste' => ''
)
```

)

And this is the debug of `$power` in the PRODUCTION server:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'id' => '1',
    'resumo' => 'Negociacao',
    'texto' => '<b>(a)</b> formalizar a transmissao, novacaoo, confissao, dacao em pagamento e transacao de obrigacoes cujo sujeito ativo (credora) seja a OUTORGANTE e as obrigacoes sejam decorrentes de suas operacoes;',
    'teste' => ''
)
```

)

This show me `Undefined index ['Power'].` but, the query works on the controller:

```
Nr  Query   Error   Affected    Num. rows   Took (ms)
 1  SELECT `Power`.`id`, `Power`.`resumo`, `Power`.`texto`, `Power`.`teste` FROM `litigium_societario`.`powers` AS `Power` WHERE 1 = 1
```

Comment: did you clear the cakephp caches (yourapp/tmp/cache/models and persistant)?.. either delete files within that folders or turn on debug for a request

Comment: I'm at lost of why the change, but to help someone else get to the solution, can you post the debug for `$poderes` instead of `$power`?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but sounds like you're getting those errors *because* your in production (**--hence no data in your database--** ... er, I guess), and you are not validating that the find() (for example) actually *has* those index.

To check, do this: focus on one action that throws that error, check if you're doing something like

```
$results = $this->Model->find('all', array('conditions'=>array(/* add a condition you know won't give any results back*/));
echo $results['Model'];
```

A find with no results will give you an empty array

```
pr($results);
//gives
Array(
);
```

and not something like

```
Array('Model'=>null)
```

So if you are trying to get a value after that without actually checking if the array has results, it will give you index notices.

That should be your error. Nonetheless, if you set debug to 0, you can bypass those pesky notices, but I would recommend checking all the actions and add a simple

```
if (count($results) > 0)
   // or
if (isset($results['Model'])
```

to avoid problems in the future and add the correct validations to include all cases.

Comment: In my local server works fine. There is data on my database of the production server...But its dont recognize the Model...I dont know why

Comment: Did you clear your caches on the production server? Remove all the files (but leave the directories intact) in /app/tmp

Comment: Actually, `if ($results) {}` or `if (!empty($results)) {}` totally suffices!

Comment: `1 SELECT `Power`.`id`, `Power`.`resumo`, `Power`.`texto`, `Power`.`teste` FROM `litigium_societario`.`powers` AS `Power` WHERE 1 = 1  `
Affected: 3
The query proceed. But, in the view, the `foreach`dont work.

Comment: @IgorMartins What's that? Could you update your question with the relevant info your putting on the comments? Besides that, on a line that's giving you that error, can you do a `pr($results)` (or whatever is giving you that problem), and post the result as an update?